# NiftyGUI's Nifty class cant instantiate?

Tags: java, exception, opengl, lwjgl, nifty-gui

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import de.lessvoid.nifty.Nifty;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.examples.LwjglInitHelper;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.nulldevice.NullSoundDevice;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.renderer.lwjgl.render.LwjglRenderDevice;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.sound.openal.OpenALSoundDevice;
import de.lessvoid.nifty.spi.time.impl.AccurateTimeProvider;

public final class Test {

    private Test(){ 
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (!LwjglInitHelper.initSubSystems("Nifty Hello World")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // create nifty
        Nifty nifty = new Nifty(new LwjglRenderDevice(), new OpenALSoundDevice(),
                LwjglInitHelper.getInputSystem(), new AccurateTimeProvider());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use NiftyGUI but it can't even pass the `nifty = new Nifty` part. I have all the dependencies.

This is the error I get for the line of `Nifty nifty = new Nifty(`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bushe.swing.event.EventTopicSubscriber
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Can someone help me out with this? I've even tried importing every nifty library.

Comment: What are you using to compile and run, and how are you trying to do that? It looks like it's just a classpath issue...

Comment: im using eclipse. i have all the .jars needed on my classpath. lwjgl.jar, lwjgl-util.jar, nifty.jar, nifty-lwjgl-renderer.jar, nifty-default-controls.jar, nifty-examples.jar, nifty-style-black.jar, xpp3-1.1.4c.jar

Comment: Well which of those (if any) contains `org.bushe.swing.event.EventTopicSubscriber`?

Comment: org.bushe.swing.event.EventTopicSubscriber is for Nifty.subscribe

[link](http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/projects/1.3/nifty/apidocs/de/lessvoid/nifty/Nifty.html)

Comment: @JonSkeet ^ this .subscribe method

Comment: @caxco93: You still haven't said which jar file contains `EventTopicSubscriber`...

Comment: @JonSkeet what can i do to know that? all i know is that Nifty.subscribe() method extends org.bushe.swing.event.EventTopicSubscriber

Comment: @caxco93: A method doesn't extend a type... Did you mean returns? I suggest you research that location (look within the jar files you've got and search on the web).

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah.. it returns 
"<T,S extends org.bushe.swing.event.EventTopicSubscriber<? extends T>> 
void".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, it looks like you're missing the [`eventbus`](http://eventbus.org/news.html) jar file. You can download the jar file from the [Maven repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/bushe/eventbus/).

Note that I didn't know anything about this class beforehand - it was merely a matter of looking carefully at the stack trace and then doing research on the internet. Simply doing a search for the class name was enough, after a few hits.